# update multiple mysql records in 1 transaction

Tags: mysql

I am trying to work out how to update a number of records in 1 transaction.

Normally in MS SQL SERVER I would go

```
Update table
set status 'YES' where ID in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', etc)
```

However in MYSQL i can't work out the right syntax.

Can I use less than, between than operators? `>= and <=` ?
Or can I use like I have done in the above statement, using `where "ID" in ('','','','')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Update table
set status = 'YES' 
where ID in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6')
```

You can also use BETWEEN

```
Update table
set status = 'YES' 
where ID BETWEEN '1' AND '6'
```

Answer (score 2):

Ex:

```
UPDATE files SET col_x = %s 
WHERE ROWID in 
(SELECT ROWID FROM table_name WHERE col_a = '%s' AND col_b = 0 );
```

You could use a nested query to select Rows and then update the rows in a single statement.

Comment: Sorry, this is a more like a generic solution.

Comment: Then in that case too, I will prefer a join, rather than a sub query, it is a hit on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes In MYSQL you are free to run the above query ::

```
Update table
set status 'YES' 
where ID in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', etc)
```

If its is a normal sequence you can try out with

**between**

```
  Update table
  set status 'YES' 
  where ID between 1 and n
```

**>= <=**

```
Update table
set status 'YES' 
where ID >=0 or ID<=n
```